# How to properly type a button click in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a button, on click on which I need to get the name of the button. How to correctly type event event by typescript? No matter how I tried it, it throws an error.

```
  const handleSortReports= (event : ??? ) => {
    const {name} = event.target
    console.log(name)
  }

<button id="Period" name="Period" type="button" onClick={handleSortReports}>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ***React.MouseEvent***

```
    const handleSortReports= (event : React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> ) => {
    const button: HTMLButtonElement = event.currentTarget;
    console.log(button.name);
  }
```

Comment: If I use your answer I have this error - TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Comment: @Timofeus91 I've updated my answer. Please check again.